# Simple polygon from unordered points

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, polygon

I've been trying to create an algorithm for finding the order of points in a simple polygon. 
The aim is when given points on a 2D plane (there is always possible to form a simple polygon btw) I output the order of points in a valid simple polygon. All points must be part of said polygon.

I've somewhat achieved this, but it fails for some test cases. The way I have done this is by finding the geometrical centre

```
int centerX = (lowX + highX) / 2;
            int centerY = (lowY + highY) / 2;

            Point center = new Point(centerX, centerY, -1);
```

and then sorting all points by their polar angle.

```
Collections.sort(points, (a, b) -> {
                if(a == b || a.equals(b)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                double aTheta = Math.atan2((long)a.y - center.y, (long)a.x - center.x);
                double bTheta = Math.atan2((long)b.y - center.y, (long)b.x - center.x);
                if(aTheta < bTheta) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if(aTheta > bTheta) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    double aDist = Math.sqrt((((long)center.x - a.x) * ((long)center.x - a.x)) +
                                            (((long)center.y - a.y) * ((long)center.y - a.y)));

                    double bDist = Math.sqrt((((long)center.x - b.x) * ((long)center.x - b.x)) +
                                            (((long)center.y - b.y) * ((long)center.y - b.y)));

                    if (aDist < bDist) {
                        return -1;
                    } 
                    else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }    
            });
```

I'm struggling with finding out what makes this break for some of the test cases. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated! Also wondering if there are any efficient, yet not overly complicated algorithms that can perform this.

**UPDATE**

I've found one of the failing test cases: When given the points `(101, 101), (100, 100), (105, 100), (103, 100), (107, 100), (102, 100), (109, 100)` Labeled 0 to 9 respectively

My program outputs `2 4 6 0 3 5 1` but it is not a valid simple polygon

It should be a permutation of `1 0 6 4 2 3 5`

Comment: Note that you can avoid the unecessary call to ````sqrt````. As this function is monotonic, the test ````sqrt(a) < sqrt(b)```` is equivalent to ````a<b````.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Java implementation of the nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61478976/6438819) already provided by **Reblochon Masque**.

Note that instead of using any trig functions to calculate angles we use a comparison of the relative orientation (or turn direction) from the min point to each of the two points being compared. Personally I find this more elegant than using angles, but others may disagree. However, as with any calculations based on `double` the `orient2D` method is susceptible to errors in rounding.

Also, when there's a tie based on orientation, because the min point and the two points are collinear, we break the tie by considering the relative ordering of the two points. This means that we'll visit points in order, with no "switchbacks", which I think is preferable.

```
static List<Point2D> simplePolygon(Collection<Point2D> points)
{       
    final Point2D min = minPoint2D(points);

    List<Point2D> simple = new ArrayList<>(points);
    Collections.sort(simple, (p1, p2) ->
    {
        int cmp = orient2D(min, p2, p1); 
        if(cmp == 0) 
            cmp = order2D(p1, p2);
        return cmp;
    });

    return simple;
}

// return lowest, leftmost point
static Point2D minPoint2D(Collection<Point2D> points)
{
    Point2D min = null;
    for(Point2D p : points)
        if(min == null || order2D(p, min) < 0) min = p;
    return min;
}

// order points by increasing y, break ties by increasing x
static int order2D(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
{
    if(p1.getY() < p2.getY()) return -1;
    else if(p1.getY() > p2.getY()) return 1;
    else if(p1.getX() < p2.getX()) return -1;
    else if(p1.getX() > p2.getX()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

// Does p involve a CCW(+1), CW(-1) or No(0) turn from the line p1-p2
static int orient2D(Point2D p1, Point2D p2, Point2D p)
{
    double dx = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
    double dy = p2.getY() - p1.getY();      
    double px = p.getX() - p1.getX();
    double py = p.getY() - p1.getY();       
    double dot = py * dx - px * dy;     
    return dot < 0 ? -1 : dot > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Test:

```
int[] a = {101, 101, 100, 100, 105, 100, 103, 100, 107, 100, 102, 100, 109, 100};

List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i+=2) 
    points.add(new Point2D.Double(a[i], a[i+1]));

List<Point2D> simple = simplePolygon(points);       
for(Point2D p : simple) System.out.println(p);
```

Output:

```
Point2D.Double[100.0, 100.0]
Point2D.Double[102.0, 100.0]
Point2D.Double[103.0, 100.0]
Point2D.Double[105.0, 100.0]
Point2D.Double[107.0, 100.0]
Point2D.Double[109.0, 100.0]
Point2D.Double[101.0, 101.0]
```

Which I believe is correct.

Answer (score 2):

here is an easy to implement `O(n logn)` algorithm that is guaranteed to produce a simple polygon (no edge crossings)

1- find the point the most south, (and the most westwards if you have a tie with the y values).

2- Sort all points based on their angle between this most south point, and the horizontal line.

3- the ordered sequence is a simple polygon.

In some rare cases, some points may not form a vertex, but be included in an edge, if they are collinear at the same angle.